# Using ~ in a shebang line

Tags: python, ubuntu, unix, shebang

I'm trying to make a runnable Python script with a custom virtual environment.
Instead of activating the virtual environment or specifying the full path I tried to use `~` in the shebang line.

- Does not work out (expected):
  `#!~/path/to/bin/python` and running the script as `./script.py`.
- Does not work out (lacks `pip` dependencies):

  `#!/full/path/to/bin/python` and running the script as `./script.py`.
- Works out:
  No shebang line and running the script as `~/path/to/venv/bin/python script.py`.

Comment: I wonder if something like this would work? `#!/usr/bin/env ~/path/to/python`

Comment: @sinoroc, with a standard-baseline `/usr/bin/env`, no, that won't work.

Comment: That said, "why" questions aren't really on-topic here unless their answers can be reasonably expected to change how you go about the practice of software development. "**How** can I use `~` in a shebang?" would be a question less likely to be closed, though it's unlikely that you'll get a very satisfying answer (you can have the shebang be a different executable that itself executes your desired Python interpreter, but that's a fair bit of work to set up).

Comment: `~` is a shell construct. The OS itself doesn't honor it as part of a path -- the shell does that. Shebangs aren't parsed by a shell but by the OS kernel itself, so shell syntax isn't expected to be honored. (Replacing an older version of this comment that had a thinko)

Comment: You want a shell's design for its interpretations of `~` to be sensitive to the context where it appears? That sounds *dangerous*.

Comment: BTW, in the Nix world I would use something like `#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell` followed by a second line of
`#! nix-shell -i python3 -p python3Packages.pillow python3Packages.ansicolor` if pillow and ansicolor are the two packages you want in your "virtualenv" (using Nix, one doesn't need virtualenv at all). (Example stolen from https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix-shell_shebang, which demonstrates what I was talking about "a different executable that itself executes your desired Python interpreter")

Comment: Thats a really good question! I was wondering about it also!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain in more detail what you want to achieve. Replace `#!/home/username/path/to/python` with `#!~/path/to/python`? Do you have a need to adapt the scripts to different home directories? Can this be done with a one-time modification or generation of the scripts? Show what exactly you tried.

Comment: Probably not what you expect, but you can create a directory named `~`. So, if home dir were honored the kernel needs to guess which one you want.